# GeoJSON. JS/NodeJS, float number. Incorrect mid point of Line (Axy Bxy)

Tags: javascript, floating-point, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geo

GEO JSON

**Point A:** {124.8046875, -22.79643932091949}
**Point B:** {143.26171875, -23.563987128451217}

Need to find mid point of this line:

**MidPoint X:** (124.8046875 + 143.26171875) / 2 = 134.033203125
**MidPoint Y:** (-22.79643932091949 + -23.563987128451217) / 2 = -23.180213224685353

Pick this MidPoint on Map and look at result.
**Problem:** If you use Max ZoomIN on map - Mid Point not located on Line

Why? Any ways to solve this problem?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7nvp.png)

Comment: What is the scale at max zoom in? What projection does the map use?

Comment: max zoom in - 20m / 50 ft. Sorry, i don't understand which projection map use. I use geojson.io for tests

Comment: We actually live on an approximately spherical planet. Flat maps project that surface onto a plane. There are several projection methods, with different advantages and disadvantages. You are effectively assuming [Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) by treating latitude and longitude as though they were Cartesian coordinates in a plane.

Comment: This does not appear to be a floating point issue. The zoom would have to be to fractions of a micron for floating point rounding to be an issue It is more likely to be related to map projections.

Comment: One thing to check: If you put a marker on A/B, do they show up as expected before/after zoom?